# how to set CSS border-left outside of box

Tags: html, css, border

I have element with 3 borders: `left (4px), top (1px) and bottom (1px)`:

[image]

But border-left looks like this:

[image]

how to set border-left outside of the box, to make render without cutting of edges?

This is Example of my code:

**HTML:**

```
<a class="element">Some Text</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.element {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    border-left: 4px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved problem using `:before` pseudo element in CSS:

```
.element {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    position: relative; /* Make sure you have this */
    padding-left: 8px; /* Nudge the text by few pixels in the box */
}

.element:before {
    content: "";
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    width: 4px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a note, you have a space between `100` and `%`, also you won't need `px` for `0` and also, you won't need `border-left` anymore :) and you welcome..

Comment: Just edited your answer, you had forgotten `padding-left` to nudge the text, you can revert the edit back if you didn't liked it :)

Answer (score 1):

This should solve the problem:

```
-webkit-background-clip:padding;
-moz-background-clip:padding;
background-clip:padding-box;
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at the simple example :

```
<div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: black; color: white; outline: thick solid #00ff00">SOME TEXT HERE</div>
<div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: black; color: white; border-left: thick solid #00ff00">SOME TEXT HERE</div>
```

this may help you.

Comment: I understand your idea, but outline can't be set only for left side of box.

Answer (score -1):

Add padding to the left side.

```
.element {
    padding-left:4px;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/4FkDX/)

Comment: This is doing same. Top and Bottom borders are cutting 2 pixels from left border.